# sql formating and extracting items (json)

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

So basically I should sum and list all products based on their name they should differ.
This would work properly if I only selected the $[*]. item from the table but if I were to select all items with $[*].
I will get the following

ROW:

```
[{"brand_name": "Product 1", "brand_id": "4", "quantity": 1}, {"brand_name": "Product 2", "brand_id": "5", "quantity": 3}]
```

RESULT:

```
{
    "brand_id": "[\"4\", \"5\"]",
    "brand_name": "[\"Product 1\", \"Product 2\"]",
    "quantity": 0
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
{
    "brand_id": "4",
    "brand_name": "Product 1",
    "quantity": 1
}
{
    "brand_id": "5",
    "brand_name": "Product 2",
    "quantity": 3
}
```

QUERY ELOQUENT:

```
public function scopegetBasicMeans($query)
{        
    $query->where('type', 1)
        ->join('report_asset', 'report_asset.report_id', '=', 'reports.id')->select(
            DB::raw('JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].name")) as brand_name'), 
            DB::raw('JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].brand_id")) as brand_id'),
            DB::raw('SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].quantity")) as quantity')
        )->orderBy('quantity', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].name")'));
}
```

QUERY RAW:

```
select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].name")) as brand_name, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].brand_id")) as brand_id, SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].quantity")) as quantity, `reports`.`created_at`, `commercialist_id`, `type` from `reports` inner join `report_asset` on `report_asset`.`report_id` = `reports`.`id` where `reports`.`object_id` = ? and `reports`.`object_id` is not null and `type` = ? and `reports`.`deleted_at` is null group by JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[*].name") order by `quantity` desc
```

Basically I should sum the quality of all items with specific name and group them by their name which will get me the unique results.
This would work if i were to select only first item from the table for example: $[0].name[0] but not on multiple.
Any suggestions?

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzQqG.png)

Comment: you appear to have got double-encoded JSON, because you're outputting a JSON string and then putting it inside another object which is then itself encoded as JSON. instead, output all your data into an object and then encode the final object, _once_.

Comment: I have trouble with indexes, arrays are multi dimensional and i dont know how to extract by index of each item

Comment: you appear to be extracting from the same "resources" table each time. What's wrong with a simple SELECT statement which selects all the columns you need? Perhaps if you show the actual SQL data structure and sample of raw data it would be clearer.

Comment: That would be cool but i need unique items for example there is multiple rows with name product 1 and for example quantity of 2 and 3, query should return only one product 1 and sum the quantity which in this case would be 5 if you understand.

Comment: use SUM and GROUP BY, then. But it can still be a single SELECT.

Comment: Could you please provide an example in the answer to see if i got the point right?

Comment: something like `SELECT id, name, SUM(quantity) from resources group by id, name`. Of course if your IDs are unique but your names are not then you might have an issue if you also need the IDs. But that would beg the question why you have such data quality issues in the first place...

Comment: That again would not work because you have to extract json item, and in order to extract it you could pass the index or you could extract all item values at once, in doing so if all values are extracted (quoted) therefore sum wont work.

Comment: "That again would not work because you have to extract json item"...what do you mean??? SQL has nothing to do with JSON. Forget about JSON...concentrate on getting the right data from your database.Then, if it's not in the final format you require for outputting as JSON, process it so that it's in the right format. Then encode it as JSON as the very last step of your script.

Comment: I wonder if you are having trouble with how to use the laravel DB:: class? Maybe try and write a raw SQL query which gets the data you need. Then after that, work out how to express in the laravel class way - or just skip that and use the RAW feature to execute the pure SQL.

Comment: I am using raw feature like this, DB::raw('SUM(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$**.quantity"))) as test'), which is returning me 0

Comment: yes I saw that already. But my point was to put your whole SQL query into one raw statement. And **stop trying to format it as JSON within the SQL**. Forget about laravel for a minute, go to Workbench or phpmyadmin or whatever you use and just figure out the pure SQL you need in order to fetch your data.

Comment: P.S. If you want some more detailed help with that then post your table structure and some sample data (from which it would be possible to get your expected output).

Comment: I have posted the structure, there is resource field, thats the one which has all json data

Comment: Right so there is JSON _within_ your columns. That was not clear at all before. I don't know if you can sum it with SQL...you might just have to extract it all and process it in PHP.

Comment: I said at the beggining what row looks like

Comment: You didn't make it clear it was _within_ a column in a table. It looked like something you had made as the result of manipulating the SQL output. Storing JSON within SQL columns is not a very common thing to do. Most people would create a proper relational table structure  for the data. Then things like grouping and sum-ing are easy with normal SQL.

Comment: Well thats what i got from this project, not how I would do it, do you have any idea how to achieve tis?

Comment: And there's no scope to re-design the data structure? If not, no I don't know if you can easily do it within SQL itself...some people have [suggestions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql+JSON+group+and+sum&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=mysql+JSON+group+and+sum&aqs=chrome..69i57.7072j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but none of it looks straightforward. The other option as I said is simply to output it from the database as-is and then use PHP to process the data.